# How to apply a function in a pairwise fashion in python with one argument and a list of arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

What is the best and fastest way to apply a function in python when:

1. A function takes two arguments
2. Argument #1 is a predefined value
3. Argument #2 is a list of values
4. I need to apply the function with Argument #1 and every element from Argument #2 list

I can do something like this:

```
result = []
for argument_from_list in arguments_list:
  result.append(my_func(predefined_value, argument_from_list))
```

I was also thinking about `map` and enclosing the value in `[]` but:

> With multiple iterables, the iterator stops when the shortest iterable is exhausted

So I could not come up with a solution involving list comprehension and some functional method although I'm sure it's possible and probably faster.

Comment: `result = [my_func(predefined_value, argument_from_list) for argument_from_list in arguments_list]`?

Comment: I can't believe I could not think of it! Long day at work lol. Would you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a list comprehension:

```
result = [my_func(predefined_value, argument_from_list) for argument_from_list in arguments_list]
```

If you want to use `map`, it takes a function that takes a single argument, so either you'll have to get a function that takes a single argument.

Using `map` and `lambda`:

```
result = list(map(lambda arg: my_func(predefined_value, arg), arguments_list))
```

Using `map` and partial function application:

```
from functools import partial

result = list(map(partial(my_func, predefined_value), arguments_list))
```

Alternatively, if you want to `zip` things up, that's possible too. There's a variant of `map` in the `itertools` standard library.

Using `itertools.starmap` and `itertools.repeat`:

```
from itertools import starmap, repeat
result = list(starmap(my_func, zip(repeat(predefined_value), arguments_list)))
```

---

I recommend going with the list comprehension.

Comment: @matszwecja beat me to it in comment